# Angular 2 / angular-cli: How to deploy on a webserver

Tags: angular, angular-cli

What software do I need on the Web server to Angular 2 app to get it working? Or I can just upload the files to the web server?

Comment: If your application is compiled, it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli)? (I'd recommend you to use it if you haven't). Because you just can do this command on your terminal

`ng build -prod --output-path=path/to/home/of/web/server/`

What it does, it builds your app and generate `dist` folder, in this case because you specified the output, it directly generate the dist content inside the path.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just upload files. Angular is a JavaScripts framework that runs on web browser.Just make sure your all TyperScipt files are complied in JavaScript.

Comment: So i need to upload the complete project folder containing the following folders e2e, node_modules and src? Can you be a little bit more specific :)

Comment: Yes, when I tested, I upload all things to server. And it was working